# Android studio arctic fox throwing "Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable",on Macbook Air M1 .anyone facing the same issue?

Tags: android, android-studio, macbookpro-touch-bar

So I installed android studio arctic fox on Macbook M1 Air, but when I tried to build it keeps throwing the error like "Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable", any kind of help would be great.Thank you.

p.s I tried adding the 'buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"' as well didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing rosetta 2, it worked for me